# Unable to install Ubuntu using Rufus

Tags: boot, system-installation, 18.04, live-usb, rufus

I am trying to install the latest version of Ubuntu, but after I choose what to do (Install Ubuntu or Try Ubuntu) I see the Ubuntu loading page and after that just a pixelized screen.

[image]

What should I do? Secure Boot is off and I used Rufus to make the bootable Ubuntu live USB.

Specs:

- mobo: Gigabyte h81 d2v
- GPU: AMD Sapphire 7870 xt oc
- CPU: Intel Core i5 4590

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the graphics driver. You can do this by editing the grub menu entry you can edit that entry temporary and disable the graphics driver.

To edit entry hit "e" key then add kernal parameter "nomodeset" to disable default open source graphics driver in my case ("Nouveau").

If it works then after installation also you need to do it first time and then open "Software & Updates" then navigate to tab "Additional Drivers" and select the proprietary driver to install.

Comment: The nomodeset did not worked.

Comment: That's strange, for now I suggest you to install ubuntu 16.04 and use "do-release-upgrade" command to go for 18.04